# Word problem, system of equations - Three Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

Trying to solve this problem.

I've tried a few ways with no luck including substituting, setting some of the equations to zero. Really just trying to understand the material.

The problem reads like this system of equations - am I way off?

x + y + z = 50
20x + 50y = 0.5
30y + 80z = 0.6

Tim wants to buy a used printer. There are three different types to choose from. If all three are used, the time it takes to finish 50 minutes. If printer X operates for 20 minutes and copier Y operates for 50 minutes, one-half of the job is completed. If printer Y operates for 30 minutes and printer Z operates for 80 minutes, three-fifths of the job is completed. Which is the fastest printer on its own? How long does it take this printer to complete the entire job working alone?

Comment: What methods are you allowed you use? I mean, are you allowed to use a graphing calculator? Then it would go very easy.

Comment: Hi - I have to solve this problem by hand - thanks for your question!

Comment: $x + y + z = \frac 1{50}$

Comment: First equation: $y=50-z-x$. Substitute this into third equation: $30(50-z-x)+80z=0.6$ and now you have two equations with two unknowns (z and x)

Comment: Yes, you are off.  When you say $x+y+z = 50$ what exactly do $x,y,z$ represent?  What does that equation *mean*.  If you look at it... it doesn't mean *anything*.

Comment: @imranfat But the equations are wrong in the first place.

Comment: thanks  @fleablood - any suggestions to get on the right track here? I'm really having a tough time getting this problem setup for some reason. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think your second and third equations are correct. If you apply the same reasoning to the first equation, that is to say, write $50x+50y+50z=1$ because every printer operates for fifty minutes and all of the job is completed, you might have more luck solving the system the ways you've already tried. (@Doug M had it right, but this is why he had it right)

Comment: @fleablood I gave an idea as to how to solve those equations, that's all

Comment: If x is how much of a job the printer can do in a minute, etc.  Then a whole job is 1.  The first equation should be $50x + 50y + 50z = 1$.  Your other two equations are correct.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Sandy knows how to solve the equations.  And I'm sure she is confused as to why she got $x = \frac {3989}{600}$ and $y = - \frac {39875}{15000}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system of equations should be
$$
50x + 50y + 50z = 1, \\
20x + 50y =0.5, \\
30y + 80z =0.6. \\
$$
Here $x$ is the fraction of the "whole job" completed by device $X$ in a minute; similarly for $y$ and $z$.

One way to solve this system is to express both $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$ from the 2nd and 3rd equation:
$$
x = {1\over20}(0.5-50y), \\
z = {1\over80}(0.6-30y);
$$
 substitute these expressions into the 1st equation (which will now have $y$ only); solve for $y$, then compute $x$ and $z$.

The solution is 
$$
x={1\over120}, \qquad
y={1\over150}, \qquad
z={1\over200}.
$$

That is, device $X$ is the fastest, and $Z$ is the slowest: ($x>y>z$).

Comment: Thanks so much for walking me through this! I hadn't considered the fact that all were running at the same time - you really helped. Any insight on how I'd solve the last part of the question? "How long does it take this printer to complete the entire job working alone?"

Comment: To answer "How long does it take this printer to complete the entire job working alone?" notice Alex said: "Here x is the fraction of the "whole job" completed by device X in a minute;"  So $x = \frac 1{120}$ means that X can do $\frac 1{120}$ of the job in a minute.  SO how many minutes will it take for $X$ to do *all* of the job.

Comment: @fleablood 120 minutes? Thank you !!!

Comment: Yes. 120 minutes, or 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ equal the time it takes for printer X to do the job, and $y$ equal etc.

The first thing to notice is that

$x + y + z$ does !!!!!NOT!!!! equal $50$.   If all three are running at the same time then then the result must be *less* than any printer running by itself so $50 \le \min(x,y,z) < x + y + z$.

Instead let $a=$ the number of sheets of paper printer X can print in a minute.  $b=$ the number of sheets of paper printer Y can print in a minute.  $c=$ the number of sheets of paper printer Z can print in a minute.

And let $N = $the number of sheets of paper in the job.

So $50a + 50b + 50c= N$ is the proper equation.

The next equation is $20a + 50b = \frac 12 N$

And the last equation is $30b+ 80 c = \frac 35 N$.

Can you take it from there.

Comment: Thanks so much - I have a much better sense on how to figure out which one is the fastest, could you help me solve the second part as well? Appreciate your insight!

Comment: Well, whichever $a,b,c$ is largest.  The values are probably going to be fractions.  Divide $N$ by the largest and that will tell you the time it takes.

Comment: $a = \frac 1{120}N$ and $b=\frac 1{150}N$ and $c = \frac 1{200}N$ so $a$ is the largest.  However many pages $N$ is X can print $\frac 1{120}$ of them in a minute.  How long it takes will be $\frac {N}{\frac 1{120}N} = 120$ minutes.

Comment: Alex's answer is very similar to mine by s/he offers a different way of thinking about it.  her/his way might be cleared than mine.  I hope between the two it will be clear how to do this.

Comment: Really helped - much appreciate it @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

Very simple (despite two answers given I hope this brings perfect clarity on how to solve your type of problem) . Printer $1$ prints at speed $x$ and the other two at $y$ and $z$ respectively. It means at its speed $x$ printer X finishes $1/x$ part of the job per minute. So, printer X will finish the whole job in $x$ minutes.

If all three are used the job gets done in $50$ minutes:

$50\cdot(1/x+1/y+1/z)=1$

If printer X and Y are used, then we have

$20\cdot(1/x)+ 50\cdot(1/y)=1/2$

And third variation:

$30\cdot(1/y)+ 80\cdot(1/z)=3/5$

Now, let’s get rid of fractions by denoting, say, $1/x=u$, $1/y=v$, $1/z=w$, and we’ll have a system:
$50(u+v+w)=1$

$20u+ 50v=1/2$

$30v+ 80w=3/5$

Now you can easily solve it. For example, find $v$ and $w$ in terms of $u$ from the second and third equation. Then plug it into the first equation and find $u$. Then you find speeds $x$, $y$, and $z$. 
The printer X should be the fastest! Careful! Z should be the slowest. Use common reasoning too. Don’t confuse speed with how much time a printer needs to get the job done. The more time a printer requires to get the job done, the slower it is!